# Shortcode not passing variable to included file

Tags: php, shortcode, variables, include

I set up a shortcode which includes a standard php/html form file.
In the form I have a hidden field where the value is a variable which is meant to be available in the form via the shortcode attributes.

The problem is that the value for clientId is not being passed from:

```
[insert-form form_location="form.php" clientId="25052"]
```

Instead I am getting the value defined as the default (NULL).
See the code below.

Shortcode:

```
function insert_the_form($atts){
$form_base = plugin_dir_path(__DIR__);

// Shortcode attributes & options
$atts = shortcode_atts(
    array(
        'form_location' => 'NULL',
        'clientId' => 'NULL' //Variable for client ID
        ), $atts, 'cm_insert_cmform'
    );

if ( isset($atts['form_location']) ){
    $form_location = $atts['form_location'];
}
if ( isset($atts['clientId']) ){
    $clientId = $atts['clientId'];
}   

ob_start();
include($form_base . 'forms/' . $form_location);
$out = ob_get_clean();

return $out;
}

add_shortcode( 'insert-form', 'insert_the_form' );
```

The form:

```
<form id="aform" method="post" action="/">
<input type="hidden" name="clientid" id="clientid" value="<?php echo $clientId; ?>" />
<input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Submit" class="button" />
</form>
```

Comment: Files that are *being* included do not have the original file's variables in scope in php.  [This SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4676007/1473550) has a good explanation.  Edit: I might make a class of static methods where each method echoed the markup of the form and accepted the $clientId as a parameter.

Comment: Ok, that helps clarify what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so somehow I got it working by changing it to this:
It looks like it didn't like 'the_clientId'. Maybe it just doesn't like capital letters????

```
[insert-form form_location="form.php" identification_number="12345"]


function insert_the_form($atts){
  $form_base = plugin_dir_path(__DIR__);

  // Shortcode attributes & options
  $atts = shortcode_atts(
  array(
    'form_location' => 'NULL',
    'identification_number' => 'NULL' //Variable for client ID
    ), $atts, 'insert_the_form'
  );

if ( isset($atts['form_location']) ){
  $form_location = $atts['form_location'];
}
if ( isset($atts['identification_number']) ){
  $form_idnumber = $atts['identification_number'];
}   

$clientId = $form_idnumber;

ob_start();
include($form_base . 'forms/' . $form_location);
$out = ob_get_clean();

return $out;
}

add_shortcode( 'insert-form', 'insert_the_form' );
```

Answer (score -2):

Using `SESSION`, storing `$clientId` to `SESSION` and calling it back in `FORM`

Comment: This should be a comment. Please don't use the answer section to post comments. You will be able to comment once have earned enough reputation